# How to write the '|' character using Jekyll and Markdown?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I am hosting a Jekyll Blog on Github and write my posts with Markdown. When I am using the '|' character, I do it the following way:

```
O = {x ∈ Z+ | x is odd and x < 10}
```

The page then shows:

```
O = {x ∈ Z+ x is odd and x < 10}
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
{% raw %}
O = {x ∈ Z+ | x is odd and x < 10}
{% endraw %}
```

How can I tell Markdown to not escape the '|' character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the generated HTML you will see it is being [interpreted as a table by Kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#tables) (which is the default Markdown processor in Jekyll). The easiest fix is to [escape it with a backslash](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#automatic-and-manual-escaping):

```
O = {x ∈ Z+ \| x is odd and x < 10}
```

Alternatively you could also use a different Markdown processor, e.g. [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) (in your `_config.yml`):

```
markdown: redcarpet
```

Or you could keep using Kramdown, but change the parser to one that doesn’t support tables, e.g. the [plain Markdown parser](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/parser/markdown.html) (again in your `_config.yml`):

```
kramdown:
  input: markdown
```